# xrdp session: Login failed for display 0

Tags: debian, xfce, xrdp

I have Debian 11 with xfce,and use xrdp.
But one day after I add a gpu on it and  it got crashed,and I tried
1 reinstall xrdp&xorgxrdp
2 edit /etc/xrdp/sesman.ini

```
  KillDisconnected=true
  Maxsessions=50
```

But nothing worked.

I read the xrdp-sesman.log

```
[20220531-09:02:08] [DEBUG] libscp initialized
[20220531-09:02:08] [DEBUG] Testing if xrdp-sesman can listen on 127.0.0.1 port 3350.
[20220531-09:02:08] [DEBUG] Closed socket 5 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 3350)
[20220531-09:02:08] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sesman with pid 1351
[20220531-09:02:08] [INFO ] listening to port 3350 on 127.0.0.1
```

Any help would be appreciated.